# ADB shows unknown device

Tags: android, adb

I've been developing in several Android devices since now but this one has me totally puzzled. ADB in Windows detects the device just fine, but I cannot make ADB recognize this device in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    device
```

1. Device is in USB debugging mode.
2. `lsusb` shows it as `Bus 003 Device 005: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc.`
3. `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file has the following line: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"`
4. `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` has `0x18d1` in a line by itself

What I've attempted so far:

1. Restart ADB server - no luck
2. Start ADB server as root - no luck
3. Add this line `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="0003", MODE="0666", GROUP="adbusers"` to `51-android.rules` and add myself to `adbusers` group. Restart `udev` and ADB - no luck

Comment: So you can not do adb install and the likes?

Comment: @Alex device shows as `????????????`, so no, I can't.

Comment: You do not really need device name to perform adb commands

Comment: @patelpratik that worked... thanks! It worked on last USB port I tried... Murphy's law I guess. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it ;)

Comment: @Alex if it shows as `????????????` it usually has no permissions or shows offline in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB port was defective. It worked fine in another USB port.